# AWS Lambda: configure logback to log to tmp folder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, logback, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an existing project which I converted to lambda function which uses logback.xml to generate logs. When I run the function, logs would be automatically attached to CloudWatch. This is expected functionality as mentioned in the AWS docs.

Due to some reasons, I don't want the logs to be moved to cloud watch, instead, I want the log file to be created under /tmp folder of lambda.

Need inputs to achieve this.

Comment: anything that logs to standard out will be captured by cloudwatch... you'll need to configure logback to write logs to a file in /tmp/ instead of standard out... it may be good to rephrase your question around this problem and add some logback tags as it's not really AWS related

Comment: If you do this then there is really no need to have a log file.  When you exit your code you can't get the logs.  Do you just want to turn logging off?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is not EC2 machine, it runs by AWS and having logs stored in a file will lead losing them forever.

There is a way to store logs and send them to s3 after that here an example

https://www.initpals.com/node-js/how-to-stream-logs-from-aws-lambda-to-s3-nodejs-example/.

Keep in mind /tmp folder has some limits like max storage size of 512 MB.

Comment: Thanks, Traycho Ivanov for your response. Above example could work in case of nodejs, but I need a similar solution in java

Comment: @user3373917 What stops use write it in java use  slf4js + logback and set it writing to tmp folder